# How to store char* dynamicly in a C++ loop?

Tags: c++, char

[Reposted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70541155/how-to-assign-char-variables-dynamicly-in-c)

I encounter a scenario to register arbitrary addresses as `char*` in a program. To simplify the problem, suppose after separating words from a sentence I need to pass each word as `char*` to the dll library for further action.
Static way to analyze "Hello World" would be like this:

```
...
#include third_party_lib;

char* w1 = "Hello".c_str();
char* w2 = "World".c_str();

third_party_function(w1);
third_party_function(w2);
```

Obviously the naming of `w1` & `w2` is static, which means I have to write their names manually. It is not suitable for passing an arbitrary number of `char*` variables to the third_party_function.

I heard it is not possible to name variables with wildcards, like `w_n`, an alternative way to do it would be using a vector or an array of `char*`.

I have come up with this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char* w[100];
  string a = "Hello";

  a.copy(w[0], a.size(), 0);
  cout << "w[0]: "<<w[0] <<endl;
  //third_party_function(w[0]);

  a = "World";
  cout << "a after: " <<a <<endl;

  a.copy(w[1], a.size(), 0);
  cout << "w[1]: "<< w[1] <<endl;
  //third_party_function(w[1]);
}
```

Note I re-used the variable `a` because it will be this case if in a loop.
However, the third output is not what supposed to be, and the print-out is only two lines:

```
w[0]: Hello
a after: World
```

Of course these are two failed attempts. But how to pass an arbitrary number of `char*` variables to a function by a third-party library, by any means?

Comment: `ch[0]` is a pointer, but you never make it point anywhere. Therefore it's invalid to use it.

Comment: instead of `char* ch[100]` why not have a vector of  std::string ? You can then pass the .data() to the dll function you call. I don't see what added value char* ch[100] has

Comment: @AndersK These 3 lines do not work in main: ```vector<char*> ch;   string a = "Hello"; 
  ch.push_back(a.data()); ```

Comment: @GeorgeY It seems like you have XY problem. Also, it is not at all clear what exactly you want and why you're using `char*`. Second, your program has undefined behavior because of using uninitialized variable. You should refer to some good books before writing any kind of program instead of doing arbitrary things and expecting that it will lead to your desired output(especially in `C++`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: ooops, right, sorry.

Comment: @GeorgeY why don't you just do `std::string a = "Hello"; third_partyfunction(a.data()); `  ? `std::vector<std::string> w{"Hello","World"}; third_partyfunction(w[0].data());`

Answer (score 2):

Avoid those pointers and array sizing issues with `string` and `vector`.  When you need to pass a `char*` from a string to an external function, you can use the `.c_str()` member of the string class.  (If you use `data()`, you aren't guaranteed of null termination, apparently).

Example:

```
vector<string> words;

string a = "Hello";
words.push_back(a); // you could also just say, words.push_back("Hello")
cout << "words[0]: "<< words[0] <<endl;

a = "World";
words.push_back(a);
cout << "words[1]: << words[1] << endl;
```

Then with your `words` vector, you can enumerate over it and get the `char*` internal to each `string` instance.

```
for (const string& word : words)
{
    some_library_function(word.c_str());
}
```

Now if `some_library_function` expects a `char*` instead of a `const char*`, which is a hint that it modifies the string in place, you'll need to make a temp copy of it:

```
for (const string& word : words)
{
    const char* str = word.c_str();
    size_t len = word.size();
    vector<char> tmp(str, str+len+1); // +1 for null char

    some_library_function(tmp.data());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer selbie. But to my knowledge, `char*` is a pointer.  And would it write multiple pointers of `char*` to the memory in the enumeration ```for (const string& word : words)``` without destroying them in the end?

Comment: What do you mean by `write multiple pointers` ?

Comment: I have learned that you cannot use `word.c_str()` directly as an input to a function. You need to first name a variable that is type `char*` and make the assignment of `word.c_str()` to it, before using that variable as a parameter in the function. Otherwise the result of function `.c_str()` is not stored at all and hence cause an error.

Comment: Show me the declaration to your function that expects a char pointer to be passed to it and describe what it does.

Comment: this line from the header file: `virtual void RegisterFront(char *pszFrontAddress) = 0;` The function `RegisterFront` can be reused any time, each register one IP address of a server. The third party library would reconnect to another IP once the current gets offline.

Comment: Ideally, you have the author of RegisterFront change the function signature to accept a `const char*` or a std::string directly.  I'm assuming RegisterFront makes a copy of the string passed in.  If that's the case, my second example is valid.

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote

```
a.copy(ch[0], a.size(), 0);//this is undefined behavior
```

You're using `ch[0]`. But since `ch` was **uninitialzied** this will lead to **undefined behavior**.

> Undefined behavior means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

For example [here](https://onlinegdb.com/XXYDiJLmh) the program doesn't seem to crash but [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ofPZf4UeGIl1Cvek) it sometimes crashes and sometimes doesn't. So don't rely on the output of the program that has UB.

If you want a `char*`, you can use a `std::string::c_str`:

```
    std::string a("Hello");

    char * cstr = new char [a.length()+1];
    std::strcpy (cstr, a.c_str()); //uses std::string::c_str 
    
    // cstr now contains a c-string copy of a
    
    //dont forget to uses delete 
    delete[] cstr;
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Comment: Yes this way fails. Could you find a way that works to " pass each word as `char*` after separating words from a sentence"?

Comment: @GeorgeY You can use [`std::string::c_str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) if you want a `char*` as shown at the end of my edited answer. Check it out.