# How to assign char* variables dynamicly in C++?

Tags: c++, char

I encounter a scenario to register arbitrary addresses as `char*` in a program.I need to pass each one as `char*` to the third party library for further action.

The third_party_function is describe as such in its header file:

```
virtual void RegisterFront(char *pszFrontAddress) = 0;
```

First, the program have to read from a config file with a group of addresses like:

```
tcp://18.19.20.22:7778; tcp://18.19.20.24:7778; tcp://18.19.20.25:7778;
```

The procedure to analyze this string and break it to a vector of addresses is simple if I define it as a cstring and use a loop. But then each has to be registered in that function in order for the library to connect to another address if current failed. Currently the configuration has 3 addresses but an arbitrary number of them should be allowed.

A static way to assign `char*` variables would be like this:

```
...
#include third_party_lib;

char* addr1 = "tcp://18.19.20.22:7778".c_str();
char* addr2 = "tcp://18.19.20.24:7778".c_str();

RegisterFront(addr1);
RegisterFront(addr2);
```

I omitted the loop to analyze the addresses out from the config, but the essence is clear: I cannot name addr[n]'s in the program since the number of addresses is uncertain - it depends on how many would be written in that config line.

i.e. For the 3 addresses scenario I can assign `addr1` `addr2` `addr3` in the code. But once it is compiled, what if the config line now contains only two addresses? What about changing to 5?

- How to improve the above to achieve dynamically assigning an arbitrary number of `char*` variables and pass each one of them to the third party function `RegisterFront`? - Of course you could replace it by some print function to try out, but the input type shall be the same.

BTW: Replacement for `RegisterFront` function:

```
void printFront(char *addr){
  cout << addr <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::string`. _"assigning an arbitrary number of char* variables"_ or even better a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Will the third-party just reject it because it is of type `string` instead of type `char*`?

Comment: If you need a `char*` to pass elsewhere from that collection, you can always use [`std::string::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data).

Comment: Yes @πάντα ῥεῖ  but `.data()` is a function, and it seems C++ forbids it to pass the result of it directly as an input to another function because char* is a pointer not a value. To create the pointer you have to name it in a variable somehow.

Comment: @GeorgeY No, pointers are also values (and the `data` function returns such a value). Whatever it is you're doing, you are misinterpreting what the problem is.

Comment: *"...because char* is a pointer not a value"* - that is patently wrong. In the context of `virtual void RegisterFront(char *pszFrontAddress)`, that `char*` parameter is a *value* (the value is an *address*, in fact, hosting type pointer-to-char).

Comment: link about using std::string and char*, https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/stdstring-character-access-and-conversion-to-c-style-arrays/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your config line is this:

```
std::string s = "tcp://18.19.20.22:7778; tcp://18.19.20.24:7778; tcp://18.19.20.25:7778;"
```

`s` can also be a char*, it doesn't matter.  At some point in your code, you've got a string representation of that config line that you've read from file or wherever.

Then to loop through that string for each URL and all your `RegisterFront` function is just this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void trim(std::string& s) {

    size_t start = 0;
    size_t end = s.size();

    while ((start < end) && isspace(s[start]))
    {
        start++;
    }

    while ((end > start) && isspace(s[end - 1]))
    {
        end--;
    }

    s = s.substr(start, end - start);
}

void RegisterAddresses(const std::string& config_line) {

    std::istringstream ss(config_line);
    std::string address;
    while (std::getline(ss, address, ';')) {

        trim(address);

        // address[0] returns a reference to the first char in the string
        // hence, &address[0] is the char* to the front of the string
        RegisterFront(&address[0]);
    }
}
```

Then when you have your config_line (either defined as a `char*` or `std::string` instance), you just invoke it either way:

```
std::string s = "tcp://18.19.20.22:7778; tcp://18.19.20.24:7778; tcp://18.19.20.25:7778;";
RegisterAddresses(s);
```

This also works (a temporary std::string is passed to RegisterAddresses - constructed from the char* passed in)

```
const char* s = "tcp://18.19.20.22:7778; tcp://18.19.20.24:7778; tcp://18.19.20.25:7778;";
RegisterAddresses(s);
```

Comment: Since C++17, `std::string::data()` is overloaded to return a non-const `char*` pointer, making the `std::vector<char> tmp` unnecessary. And since C++11, you can alternatively just use `&address[0]` instead, since `std::string`'s data is guaranteed to be sequential in memory and null-terminated (and even before C++11, that was likely to be true in most common implementations anyway). But, if `RegisterFront()` will not modify the data passed to it, you can safely use `const_cast<char*>(address.c_str())` instead in all C++ versions.